# Char pointer array and double pointer

Tags: c++, pointer-to-pointer

How the memory allocation is done for a char pointer array and double pointer.

```
char *s[]={"knowledge","is","power"}; 
char **p;
 p=s;
 cout<<++*p<<*p++<<++*p<<endl;
```

In the above code output is --
nowledge  nowledge s

My question is just , how the values are assigned to pointer p and how it's incremented.

Comment: Because this is undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Maybe, if you provided a [mcve], the expected and the actual output, your question would become much clearer. Also, in case you are struggling with the English language, maybe there is a Stackoverflow cousin in a different language. I also wouldn't mind having it here in two languages, so that people could help you translate.

Comment: Here output provided in question is output given by compiler. my question is just , how these values are assigned and updated.